# Which engine is technically compatible with a Toyota Yaris 63KW 1300cc manufactured in 2007?

Tags: toyota, gasoline, yaris

I have an engine damaged in a way it would be cheaper to change it rather than to mend it.

The current engine model code is`2SZFE`and is emitting 136g of CO² per Km.
Following the yellow jaket (« gillets jaune ») fuel tax protests, the French government [announced a grant increase to 4000€ in our vehicle scrappage scheme for peoples buying a used car emitting less than 122g per Km](http://www.europe1.fr/politique/carburants-edouard-philippe-annonce-une-surprime-a-la-conversion-de-4000-euros-pour-les-plus-modestes-3800078) which in our free market will only rise the value of such cars instead of helping the target peoples of course.

So since the engine needs to be changed anyway, I’m interested in changing for a less powerful gasoline engine which would emit less than the required limit.
While there are Europeans Toyota Yaris manufactured in 2007 that do emit less than 122g of CO² per Km, I’m unsure if it is technically possible to use a`1NRFE`or a`1KRFE` for example.

By compatible, I mean I want to avoid spending more than 50€ for changing incompatible parts which might (I dunno) include the gearbox or the ecu.

## Update :

I went to ask for a`1KRFE`.
But if you want to change the engine of your car in France, you are required to ask for the manufacturer permission (or authorities will refuse homologation). I thought I could debunk usual claims for their refusal by choosing a less powerfull engine.
But it appears they still chose the answer that give them hope you’ll be forced to change your car for buying a new one from them (as usual).

So the answer is no even if the raised safety issues are spurious (such as the  the exageration of homologation costs or the claim the brakes wouldn’t be powerfull enough compared to power of the new engine even if the previous and first engine is more powerfull).

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Where are you getting the "136g of CO² per KM" figure from for the 2SZFE engine? Is this something the French government puts out for the engine or is it an actual reading taken from the engine in the vehicle?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 It’s a number of the V7 field on the European Union  [Vehicle registration certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_certificate). Since I need to change the engine, I’m good for paying the huge homologation cost anyway. Any engine model below 1200cc or created after 2006 should be below the official limit.

Comment: I'd make sure that you are able to re-register the car once the lower emissions engine has been fitted and are still eligible for the subsidy.

Comment: This story raises so many questions... This is for the resale value of the car and not for recurring road taxes, right? I'm afraid that the value of an 11-year old Yaris will not dramatically change from an engine swap. You are also aware that your vehicle needs to be re-registered after the engine swap?

Comment: @SteveMatthews as long as the V7 field is below 130 and the registration date after 2006, it is eligible. The problem is changing the field. In order to change the engine, I need ask the permission to the manufacters. And manufacturers near always give the answer which will require buying a new car in the hope you will purschase it at them (because it is illegal to use a car on public roads with a different horse power than the one specified on the certificate). But again as serial numbers will be different too, I need to do this even if I replace the engine by the same model.

Comment: @MadMarky changing the engine will rise questions on why the operation was performed, but I don’t have the choice. But it’s still for increasing  the plan of the goverment is to help peoples buying a car which doesn’t pollute a lot whether it’s new or a used one. So if my car is certified for emitting less than 130g of CO² per Km, the person who will buy it (if he/she fullfill all requirements) will be able to claim up to 4000€ from the state as financial help for buying the car.

Comment: @MadMarky it’s our https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrappage_program#France. it also applies to used cars and there’s a 130g of CO² per km limit. The car also needs be manufactured after 2011 for diesel engines and after 2006 for other fuel systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the two options you suggested in turn:

**1NRFE**

You're going to go screaming past that 50€ figure for ancillary changes I'm afraid - the 1NRFE will *definitely* need a new ECU, not only does it have the updated "Dual-VVTi" vs the 2SZ-FE's "single" but it also has stop-start (which is partly where the emissions improvements come from) so not only are you going to need a new ecu but a new battery, starter motor and likely a fair chunk of the loom will be different too. I'm also reasonably sure that the French-spec will have EGR as well which I don't believe the S2Z-FE had so there's going to be some exhaust plumbing changes going on there too.

**1KRFE**

There's likely to be some adaption involved in fitting this one - it's a 3-cylinder engine rather than the 4-pot 1.3 of the 2SZ-FE, which will likely mean changes to engine mounts, gearbox you *should* be okay (depending upon which transmission you have already) and again you're going to need a new ECU and there'll be some loom changes as well.

Comment: I have currently an electronic stick stick shift gearbox, but it current works well with my de-facto 3‒cylinder engine (1 cylinder is broken beyond repair which is why the engine needs to be replaced). Will I need to change the starter motor and the battery for the`1KRFE`model ? Concerning the`1NRFE`I’m sure the stop and start feature is always optional whatever the engine. Or at least in France.

Comment: @user2284570 I wouldn't have thought you'd need to change starter/battery for the 1KR-FE, you will need an appropriate ECU and engine loom though and ideally I'd say you're better off sourcing one that came out of a Yaris with the same transmission to make that easier. I'm not convinced there aren't going to be a handful of other minor changes to make that will make the 50€ changes budget unrealistic.

Comment: @user2284570 additionally if the goal is to bolster the resale value (by becoming eligible for the subsidy) then won't most of that be offset by fact that most people would run screaming from something that's had an engine conversion?

Comment: Yes, but I can’t keep the current engine because it is broken. Peoples would be screaming even if I replace the engine by a same model.

Comment: @user2284570 it might be a cultural difference.. here in the UK a like-for-like replacement engine is often a good selling point but anything with a conversion is viewed by non-enthusiasts as a huge negative.

Comment: @user2284570 another thing I might be having trouble wrapping my head around is the difference in local markets - here you're practically tripping over decent 2nd hand Yaris with the engine(s) you want for about a 1000€ so a swap doesn't make sense economically. Presumably things like the subsidy make things quite a bit different!

Comment: Hemm yes, the cheapest car below 140000km with an electronic stick shift gearbox or ᴄᴠᴛ with a ʟᴘɢ equipment (this was what I was looking for) was a 120 000Km lancia musa manufactered in 2008. Despite having the valvetrain needing to be changed ᴀꜱᴀᴘ, it was sold at 4700€ in less than 24h. The next one was a 100000Km Dodge caliber at 5500€ and had 2000€ sales quote in order to get the engine working again. It was sold in 2 weeks. **This is the current situation without the grant increase**. I agree that if I could use a car requiring full clutch control, things would have been cheaper.

Comment: And for the engine conversion, I’m not required to tell the previous engine was a`2SZFE`. Since there are Toyota Yaris manufactered in 2007 with a`1KRFE`engine. Letting suppose the engine was replaced by a same model.

Comment: And it looks likes I have an other problem with the actual de facto 3 cylinder engine because of a mistake by a mechanic https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/61348. Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: @user2284570 seeing from that question that you have a 3rd party LPG kit fitted - this further complicates any potential engine swap. Honestly I can't see any way a swap on this is going to be cheaper than just selling the car for scrap and buying a replacement.

Comment: In France, you don’t sell your car for scrap. You give it for scraping for free (you need to get the registration certificate destroyed). And as I said it’s really hard to find something below 6000€ for those set of option and car mileage (without the grant). Though the garage told me a new cylinder head would cost 2000€ alone. But turned out I found far cheaper. So the engine can be repaired.

Comment: @user2284570 Glad you got it sorted.